# TcpClient SocketException .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, tcpclient

My computer is configured to automatically obtain IP address. When I use `ipconfig /all`, it shows something like below:

```
Windows IP Configuration

PPP adapter Broadband Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 95.38.95.204
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64d7:e4ee:ba7e:1ede
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.72.198
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Should I use `95.38.95.204` or `192.168.72.198` as IP address for server and client?

When I used `192.168.72.198`, server connected successfully but client threw an `SocketException` like below

```
 var tcpServer = new TcpClient();
 tcpServer.Connect(new IpAddress("192.168.72.198"), 1986);
```

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.72.198:1986

I used this articles on geekpedia at http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html

Thanks if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing it on your own computer you can use `127.0.0.1` or `"localhost"`.

You should use the IPv4 address generally (`192.168.72.198`).

It sounds like you don't have your server already running on that socket.

Comment: thanks, but article author said we can use 192.168.72.198 and this should be works properly. but on my computer not. i need to change any section on network setting? i'm using windows 7, ilso when i turn off my adsl modem and get ipconfig command, result is nothing and says Media disconnected

Comment: I agree with Graphain; the most likely reason for that error is that your server process is not running. You can test this by running `netstat -a` and looking for port `1986` in a `Listening` state. Regarding your comment, you need a network to have a network address; this is why 192.168.72.198 goes away when you turn off your modem.

Comment: @Stephen when i run netstate -a on cmd that shows this: **TCP 192.168.72.198:1986 Sadegh-PC:0 LISTENING** but still my client can't connect to this ip:port and SocketException was thrown(timeout and connection failed)

Comment: Try using `IPAddress.Any` for your server's IP. That's the standard practice for servers.

Comment: It might be listening, but is it actually responding? If you do `telnet 192.168.72.198 1986` in a command prompt, and pretend to be the client and send whatever the client would by typing it and hitting enter what happens?